# Sikulix/java error: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1

Tags: java, debian, sikuli-x

I am running sikulix on debian 12: `sudo java -jar sikulixide-2.0.5-lux.jar` with sudo privileges, otherwise there are mouse errors. Sikulix runs great so far except when calling `Region.text()`.

For example: `print(Region(300,500,100,50).text())`

gives the Error:
`[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ( java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1 )`

how can I install this class?

`Region(x,y,w,h)` xy center coordinates, width, height

`text()` calls OCR text recognition on a region on the screen.

Comment: I would *begin* by ensuring tesseract is installed: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install tesseract-ocr`

Comment: Then, make sure your java Tesseract jar(s) present in classpath

Comment: `tesseract-ocr` is installed. How do I check Tesseract jar(s) are present in classpath?

Comment: Sorry, that was wrong. Let me check

Comment: If you've found you need Tesseract, you probably need to do `java -cp tess4j.jar:sikulixide-2.0.5.jar org.sikuli.ide.Sikulix` after getting Tess4J

Comment: It still shows the same error. Here is the full error:

`[error] script [ TEST ] stopped with error in line 1
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError ( java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract1 )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first
line: module ( function ) statement 
1: main (  <module> )     print(Region(300,500,100,50).text())
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------`

Comment: Please say exactly what you're doing when this happens and how you started the app. Bear in mind that I know nothing about this application

Comment: The app started normally (it takes a little longer to load with the added tess4j.jar) in terminal with `sudo java -cp tess4j.jar:sikulixide-2.0.5.jar org.sikuli.ide.Sikulix` the tess4j.jar file is in the same folder as sikulixide-2.0.5.jar.
The gui app opens and I run the test `print(Region(300,500,100,50).text())`. It hides the gui sikulix and tries to run the code "recognize text (OCR) on specific region on screen and print out string". The gui comes back and shows the error in the message tab.

Comment: There's another jar called sikulixide-2.0.5-lux.jar for Linux. Try that one. It's got the Tess4J classes in it

Comment: sorry yes I used the sikulixide-2.0.5-lux.jar file. I just copy pasted and added the sudo but it is the lux.jar version.

Comment: I tried again without sudo and it took me straight to https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1/wiki/macOS-Linux:-Support-libraries-for-Tess4J-Tesseract-4-OCR I have tesseract installed as in the link but it's a newer version 5.3.0. Maybe I should install the 4.1.0 version?

Comment: Then you should never have got class not found as they are in the same jar. Difficult to sort this out as for some very weird reason, the app deletes itself!

Comment: I tried without sudo and got a new error: `[error] org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception ( org.sikuli.script.SikuliXception: OCR: start: Tesseract library problems: Error looking up function 'TessBaseAPIInitLangMod': /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so: undefined symbol: TessBaseAPIInitLangMod )` It looks like sudo was doing something.

Comment: Now that *does* look possibly like a (lib) Tesseract versioning problem

Comment: tried uninstalling tesseract-ocr and compiling from source different versions of tesseract (4.1.0, 4.1.2) still same error.

Comment: I have /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtesseract.so.4.0.1 on Debian Bullseye and it *does* contain that symbol